# В событии SelectionIndexChanged для Combobox не заносятся данные в поле класса

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, telerik

Я создал в коде страницы поле "rcbSelection". Далее в событии Page_Load() я инициализирую его и после в нескольких событиях SelectionIndexChanged для Combobox добавляю данные.

```
public partial class AddToProcurementPlan : Page
{
private Dictionary<string, int?> rcbSelection;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        rcbSelection = new Dictionary<string, int?>();
        /*other code*/
    }
 }

protected void rcb_FinancingBudget_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox rcb = (RadComboBox)sender;
    if (rcbSelection.ContainsKey("financingbudget"))
        rcbSelection["financingbudget"] = int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue);
    else
        rcbSelection.Add("financingbudget", int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue));
}

protected void rcb_BudgetName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox rcb = (RadComboBox)sender;
    if (rcbSelection.ContainsKey("budget"))
        rcbSelection["budget"] = int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue);
    else
        rcbSelection.Add("budget", int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue));
}

protected void rcb_FondName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox rcb = (RadComboBox)sender;
    if (rcbSelection.ContainsKey("fond"))
        rcbSelection["fond"] = int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue);
    else
        rcbSelection.Add("fond", int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue));
}

protected void rcb_Kfkr_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox rcb = (RadComboBox)sender;
    if (rcbSelection.ContainsKey("kfk"))
        rcbSelection["kfk"] = int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue);
    else
        rcbSelection.Add("kfk", int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue));
}

protected void rcb_Kekr_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox rcb = (RadComboBox)sender;
    if (rcbSelection.ContainsKey("kekr"))
        rcbSelection["kekr"] = int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue);
    else
        rcbSelection.Add("kekr", int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue));
}

protected void rcb_BudgetExec_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox rcb = (RadComboBox)sender;
    if (rcbSelection.ContainsKey("budgetexec"))
        rcbSelection["budgetexec"] = int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue);
    else
        rcbSelection.Add("budgetexec", int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue));
}

protected void rcb_SectionCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox rcb = (RadComboBox)sender;
    if (rcbSelection.ContainsKey("section"))
        rcbSelection["section"] = int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue);
    else
        rcbSelection.Add("section", int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue));
}

protected void rcb_TargetArticle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox rcb = (RadComboBox)sender;
    if (rcbSelection.ContainsKey("targetarticle"))
        rcbSelection["targetarticle"] = int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue);
    else
        rcbSelection.Add("targetarticle", int.Parse(rcb.SelectedValue));
}
}
```

Однако, когда я ставлю точку остановки на последнем событии, в отладчике я вижу, что словарь rcbSelection пустой после последовательного выбора элементов в Combobox. Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Что то я не понял, вы в page_load создаете словарь. Page_Load вызывается на каждый постбек. То есть при каждом постбеке, каждый раз, когда вы что то выбираете в любом из ваших контролов, которые отправляют постбек, вы словать создаете заново. Между постбеками словать не живет, он на каждый постбек создается заново, туда заносится запись и после он уничтожается.

Comment: если вы хотите что либо хранить между постбеками, вы можете хранить это во ViewState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объекты страниц в asp.net живут только на время запроса. Происходит примерно следующее:

1. Приходит запрос на отображение страницы. Создается объект AddToProcurementPlan, в нем вызывается OnInit, OnLoad, OnPreRender/Render. Статические контролы создаются на OnInit, динамические - на OnPreRender. Данные о том, какие именно динамические контролы были созданы, и как были изменены свойства контролов складываются во ViewState (или ControlState).
2. На клиенте происходит что-то, для чего есть обработчик на серверной стороне (SelectedIndexChanged). На сервер приходит новый запрос. Создается новый объект AddToProcurementPlan, в нем вызывается OnInit, OnLoad, OnPreRender/Render. При этом ему подсовывается ViewState из предыдущего запроса, и свойства контролов читаются из него.

При этом создается иллюзия, что объект AddToProcurementPlan тот же самый - ведь измененные свойства сохраняют свои значения. Но для того, чтобы кастомные свойства стали сохранять свои значения, их нужно положить во ViewState. Примерно так:

```
private Dictionary<string, int?> rcbSelection 
{
    get 
    {
        var selection = (Dictionary<string, int?>)ViewState["rcbSelection"];
        if (selection == null)
        {
            selection = new Dictionary<string, int?>();
            rcbSelection = selection;
        }
        return selection
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["rcbSelection"] = value;
    }
}
```

Кроме этого нужно совсем убрать создание rcbSelection из PageLoad (т.к. PageLoad вызывается при каждом действии на странице).

Еще лучше - вообще не пишите на старом asp.net. Это мертвая технология (причем умерла она во многом из-за вот этого подхода с ViewState), нет никакого смысла тратить на нее свое время.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это мне помогло, совсем позабыл про ViewState.